# Problema en suma javascrip

Tags: javascript

estoy teniedo un pequeño problema estoy tratando de sumar +1 en javascript y mes de sumar me lo esta concatenando.

```
      if (!pagaSipa) {
    console.log(totalAPagar); // 111.81
    totalAPagar += categoriaCorrespondiente.aportes_sipa;
    console.log(totalAPagar); //605.12
    //se aumenta un aporte de obra social por cada familair extra

    //familiaresExtra = 1
    if (familiaresExtra > 0) {
      console.log(totalAPagar); //605.12
      totalObraSocial =
        categoriaCorrespondiente.aportes_obra_social * (familiaresExtra + 1); //Eror aca devuelve 7579

      console.log(totalObraSocial); //Eror aca devuelve 7579

      totalAPagar += totalObraSocial;
    } else {
      totalAPagar += categoriaCorrespondiente.aportes_obra_social;
    }
  }
```

Comment: ¿Y si a la variables `familiaresExtra` la pasas como argumento de la función `parseInt()` para que tome el valor como número?

Comment: Si me funciona correctamente :) si un error muy tonto.